# Run pytest script simultaneously with different occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I want to execute pytest script simultaneously with different occurrence

Exemple for two Pytest script that I wish to run :

Script 1 : test_print1.py

```
def test_print(config_file):
    assert config_file

    res = 0
    assert res is 0
```

Script 2 : test_print2.py

```
def test_print(config_file):
    assert config_file

    res = 0
    assert res is 1
```

So here the two scenarios that I want to have (for example) :

- Execute the two scripts simultaneously, but I want test_print1.py to be run two time and test_print3.py three times
- Execute the two scripts simultaneously, but I want test_print1.py to be run on time and test_print3.py four times

I want to the execution happen in a single command line.

I've seen **pytest-repeat** but it repeats all the test n times which don't help here.

And I have also seen **@pytest.mark.repeat(n)** which must have it hard coded into my code and this doesn't help because every time I must go into the code and change it.

*So is there any way to run multiple test simultaneously with different occurrence?*

Comment: Why would you want test scripts to repeat? What benefit is there over running each test exactly once?

Comment: There are some feature that we need to run a stress test (for example 100 times) and there are some feature that we just want to verify if it is functional or not. So the goal is to execute the whole tests in a single time to avoid sitting behind the screen waiting for each test to complete and run another

Comment: does `pytest test_print3 -n 3 && pytest test_print1.py -n 2` work?

Comment: In this case the test report will be with only one test, not with the whole tests